# why won't my object move in the render

Tags: rendering, shrinkwrap, ocean-simulation

I have made my first Blender render.

I've modelled an AtoN (a green bouy).
In layout in moves on the waves, and the light flashes correctly.

Whe I render in Cycles (GPU compute) or in Eevee:

- the light flashes correctly
- the ocean moves correctly
- the bouy and the shrinkwrapplane are static on 1 location.

What am I doing wrong, or forgetting?

In layout, all is well:
[image: In layout, everything goes well when moving]

In Render, plane and bouy are static:
[image]

Comment: did you maybe do "render image" instead of "render animation"?

Comment: @ETHANDAY, thnx for your quick response. No I first rendered the animation, with the same result. If i do render image, same problem

Comment: hm, ok.  Could you share your file?  you can use this link:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok nevermind I’m an idiot.I forgot to tick of the render box

Comment: lol, it happens